# Is there a non-overlapped window? If so, what does it look like?

Tags: windows, winforms

I've been reading some info on [window creation styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600.aspx) and found the term "overlapped window" being used for basically all windows I can think of. The word "overlap" seems misused to me, since in the context of the window itself it isn't overlapped with anything. And I couldn't find any information about how to create non-overlapped windows, so I can't instantiate one and see the difference.

Is there such a thing as non-overlapped window? If there is, please post a comparison image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on MSDN documentations there are 5 different [Window Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx#types) and based on descriptions, Child Windows and Message-Only windows are not overlapped.

Here is a summary about different window types:

- **Overlapped Windows**

  A top-level window that has a title bar, border, and client area; it is meant to serve as an application's main window. It can also have a window menu, minimize and maximize buttons, and scroll bars. An overlapped window used as a main window typically includes all of these components.
- **Pop-up Windows**

  A pop-up window is a special type of overlapped window used for dialog boxes, message boxes, and other temporary windows that appear outside an application's main window.
- **Child Windows**

  A child window is confined to the client area of its parent window. An application typically uses child windows to divide the client area of a parent window into functional areas. A child window must have a parent window. The parent window can be an overlapped window, a pop-up window, or even another child window.
- **Layered Windows**

  Using a layered window can significantly improve performance and visual effects for a window that has a complex shape, animates its shape, or wishes to use alpha blending effects. The system automatically composes and repaints layered windows and the windows of underlying applications.
- **Message-Only Windows**

  A message-only window enables you to send and receive messages. It is not visible, has no z-order, cannot be enumerated, and does not receive broadcast messages. The window simply dispatches messages.

Comment: mm, I guess that technically answers my question, and still I don't know what the visual difference is (except for the invisible message-only window type)

Comment: An example of a Child Window is a `Control` which is hosted in a `Form`.

Comment: Yes, controls are window too.